# How do I remove objects from an arraylist which are present in another arraylist based on one member variable of the object in Java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, duplicates, removeall

I have a POJO class A with the below structure

```
class A{
private String var1;
private int var2;
private String var3;
}
```

I have two `ArrayList<A> List1` and `List2` with different size. I want to remove all elements in `List1` which are already present in `List2` and this equality needs to be checked with respect to the value stored in `var2`.

I have already checked making the List a `Hashset` and using `removeAll()`. But this wont give the desired output since for the same `var2`, `var1` values differ.

Please help me solve this problem.

Edit 1 - Requested by Murat

```
public class HistoryDto implements Serializable,Comparable<HistoryDto> {

    private Integer id;
    private String sId;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSId() {
        return sId;
    }

    public void setSId(String sId) {
        this.sId = sId;
    }

    public String getTrackName() {
        return trackName;
    }

    public void setTrackName(String trackName) {
        this.trackName = trackName;
    }

    public String getTrackDescription() {
        return trackDescription;
    }

    public void setTrackDescription(String trackDescription) {
        this.trackDescription = trackDescription;
    }

    public Integer getUsedNo() {
        return usedNo;
    }

    public void setUsedNo(Integer usedNo) {
        this.usedNo = usedNo;
    }

    public String getExtraInfo() {
        return extraInfo;
    }

    public void setExtraInfo(String extraInfo) {
        this.extraInfo = extraInfo;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Integer getPartyId() {
        return partyId;
    }

    public void setPartyId(Integer partyId) {
        this.partyId = partyId;
    }

    private String trackName;
    private String trackDescription;
    private Integer usedNo;
    private String extraInfo;
    private String imageUrl;
    private Integer partyId;


    public int compareTo(HistoryDto other) {
        return this.sId.compareTo(other.sId);
    }


}
```

Removing Items

```
ListA.removeAll(new HashSet(listB));
```

Comment: How about implementing `Compareable<T>`?

Comment: @MuratK. tried and not working. Thanks

Comment: Oh it's working for sure, but you probably did it not correctly. You might want to post it here so people can actually help you.

Comment: @MuratK. code updated in question

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 loops nested.

pseudocode:

```
for each in A do
    for each in B do
       if (current item of A equals to current item of B)
           say yes!
    done
done
```

You just need to translate it to Java.

Comment: I ended up doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it using the *Stream API*:

```
Set<Integer> var2 = list2.stream()
    .map(a -> a.var2)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
list1.stream()
    .filter(a -> !var2.contains(a.var2))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: the project is built in Java7

Comment: sure. You need to define the two lists: `list2` and `list1` containing your elements of type `A`. You need to build it with *Java 1.8* because it uses *Java Streams* and *Java Lambdas*.